# C# Excel Find and Replace without pop-up dialogue showing

Tags: c#, excel, replace

When I export to Excel in C#, I want to replace some string like %find%.

If the replace returns null e.g. 'there are no string like %find%' it will always shows a pop-up dialog box, which tells me it could not not find to replace.

How I can hide the pop-up dialog box?

```
**My replace method is:`xSheet.Cells.Replace(strong textwhat, replace);`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._application.displayalerts(v=office.11).aspx